# Where to find a Nusach Maharitz siddur?

Tags: prayer-book, nusach-ashkenaz, nusach-sefard, nusach-ari

Nusach Maharitz is the nusach used by [Dushinsky Chassidim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dushinsky_(Hasidic_dynasty)), and it blends elements from Nusach Ashkenaz and Nusach Sefard almost equally, according to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nusach_Sefard) regarding N''S.

I am interested in obtaining such a siddur. Does anyone know where one could purchase one? (Online, of course.)

Also, in least priority, what is the history behind this nusach, and how close to N"A is it?

Comment: מהרי"ץ was Hungarian  misnaged,  not  chassidsee the Wikipedia about him

Comment: @kouty - I find it odd that Wiki would get something like mixing up a Chassidic dynasty and a misnaged so wrong. Do you have a source to prove that Maharitz was a misnaged. If he was, why did he make a Nusach Sefard siddur?

Comment: https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/יוסף_צבי_דושינסקי   @Ezra Hoerster

Comment: @kouty - The Maharitz was not-Zionistic, if that's what you mean...

Comment: ולמורת רוחם של חלק מהחסידים שהתנגדו לרב דושינסקי בשל היותו מתנגד[4].

Comment: see this journal http://jpress.org.il/Olive/APA/NLI_Heb/SharedView.Article.aspx?parm=lnw0ptrVxhDahlmwFCXdzjictJF8SGHynv1IOIbCuZCv1iOdt4McBCnnd9jVw%2F7BYw%3D%3D&mode=image&href=DHY%2f1932%2f09%2f19&page=3&rtl=true

Comment: @kouty - Wow, there's nothing more explanatory than that. Know, it makes me wonder why the Wikipedia has this so wrong...

Comment: If he were a misnaged, then why was he referred to as an אדמו"ר?

Comment: They were Misnagdim back in Europe, however since the mid 20th century they've been chassidish since moving to Eretz Yisroel and America.

Comment: @yyb896 No I think it's more Wikipedia doesn't know the difference between Charedi and Chassidish.

Comment: No, it's not Wikipedia. I know people who learn and daven in Dushinsky in Williamsburg who are chassidish through and through. I know a rebbe whose grandson made a shidduch with the Dushinsky Rav in Mea Shearim some time ago as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The publisher is Miller Publishing. Here is a [link](https://millerbooks.co.il/) to their website.

Here is their contact information

Rehov HaOman 26 
9342180 Yerushalayim 
Israel

To call from the USA
Tel: 011 972 2 678 3806
Fax: 011 972 2 678 1696

Comment: All of the siddurim they sell here are of the name "Siddur Bais Tefillah." I have seen these siddurim elsewhere. Are they true Nusach Maharitz?

Comment: @EzraHoerster: I do not know. I do know they published the Siddur you are looking for. You should contact them and hopefully they can assist you further.

Comment: I see. OK, I'll see if I can get to them. How do you know they sell such siddurim?

Comment: @EzraHoerster: I do not know. I do know they published the Siddur you are looking for. So if anyone sells it, it will be them. You should contact them and hopefully they can assist you further. To the best of my knowledge it was last published in 1991.

Comment: https://books.google.co.il/books/about/סידור_מהרי_ץ_לשבת_ויו.html?id=zsZaNQEACAAJ&redir_esc=y

Comment: Just realized I forgot to mark this answer correct! Sorry, @GershonGold!